# PHP time() function is 800 seconds ahead of JavaScript Date.now()

Tags: javascript, php, time

I am implementing a JWT token system and I am adding client-side token validation for a better user experience.

However, PHP `time()` function is around 800 seconds behind Javascript `Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)`.

Any idea why?

Comment: JS time is your systems time. PHP time is your servers time. check your configuration for both.

Comment: @MauriceNino Aren't they supposed to be standardized Epoch times?

Comment: Everyone can set their computer to whatever time they want. It is strongly recommended to use a time server, but this is not enforced by anyone. As @MauriceNino said, check the time on both devices and see which is closest against a third time source. When I build systems that require time in JS, I always send the server's time as a seed to get the offset in userland. It is usually negligible, but sometimes way off.

Comment: @Wyatt They *could* both be taken from the internet, but don't have to be. Check your configs and if that's not the case, at least you can rule out that factor,